# Phaser 3: Why is this.physics.add.overlap interpreted as false on update even though there is an overlap?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to detect an overlap between the player and a ladder in a static group. I have a variable "this.onLadder", which is set to false in the constructor and then I am setting it to true when there is an overlap, but for some reason it changes back to false again in my update function, so when the player is overlapping with the ladder it keeps changing between true and false. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

My constructor function looks like this:

```
constructor() {
    super('scene1'); // key: scene1

    this.score = 0;
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.onLadder = false;
    this.isClimbing = false;
  }
```

Here is my create function:

```
create() {
    this.createPlatforms();
    this.createLadders();
    this.createPlayer();
    this.createBackground();
    this.createCursor();
    this.createJumpButton();
    this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 2048);

    this.scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });
  }
```

This is how I am creating the ladder:

```
  createLadders() {
    this.ladders = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.ladders.create(300, 510, 'ladder');
    this.ladders.setDepth(1);
  }
```

and in my createPlayer function I have added:

```
this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.ladders, this.detectOverlap);
```

and the detectOverlap function just looks like this:

```
  detectOverlap() {
    this.onLadder = true;
    console.log(`detect on ladder ${this.onLadder}`);
  }
```

In my update function I am then trying to check if this.onLadder is true and then allow the player to climb, but it doesn't work because this.onLadder keeps returning false.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does it mean that the constructor is called more then one time ?

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe I am missing something. I'll try to make a codepen to show you what's going on.

Comment: By making the codepen I actually somehow fixed the issue. I am still not entirely sure what I was doing wrong, but I think it may have had something to do with my "onLadder" variable being inside the constructor function because when I moved it to the top of the codepen it suddenly worked.
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/bGbwOrO

Comment: Well done, nice to see it working :)